# JavaScript Code is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The below piece of code is not working in IE8, but, it is working perfectly on FireFox and Google Chorome, Even, there is no error thrown by IE8, but, output is not coming. Any Idea? What is the actual problem?

```
<html>
   <head/>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         (function(){
         var inpEle = document.createElement("div");
         inpEle.setAttribute("id", "div1");  
         var texEle = document.createTextNode("This is my Sample Para. I am testing it again my own level that prove How i am capable of.");
         inpEle.appendChild(texEle);
         document.body.appendChild(inpEle);
         })();
         (function(){
         var inpEle1 = document.createElement("input");
         inpEle1.setAttribute("type", "button");inpEle1.setAttribute("value", "Show");inpEle1.setAttribute("onclick", "Show()");  
         document.body.appendChild(inpEle1);
         var inpEle2 = document.createElement("input");
         inpEle2.setAttribute("type", "button");inpEle2.setAttribute("value", "Hide");inpEle2.setAttribute("onclick", "Hide()");  
         document.body.appendChild(inpEle2);
         })();
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload= function(){
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
         }
         Show = function (){
         document.getElementById('div1').style.border="2pt solid green";
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display="";
         }
         Hide = function(){
         document.getElementById('div1').style.border="";
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style. As it it is now, the code is very difficult to read. If you are alone working on the code you can format it however you want to. But if you expect others to read your code, you should put effort into making it as readable as possible.

Comment: You'e now indented your HTML, but not used indentation within your code to enhance its readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use setattribute use anonymous function for events

```
            inpEle1.onclick = function() {
                Show();
            };
```

Also it works in IE tester in IE8, but not IE7, do you have it using IE7 compatibility

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to use `document.body.appendChild()` in IE8 before the `</body>` tag has been parsed and your code is trying to append to the body while it is still being parsed.  Early versions of IE like IE6 might just abort (e.g. literally crash) when you did this.  Later versions (like IE8) will just simply ignore your request.

You can use `document.write()` to add content while the body is being parsed.

You can postpone calling your code until after the body has finished loading and parsing (such a `<body onload="xxx()">` handler) or when an event such as `window.onload` fires.

You can `appendChild()` to an element that has finished parsing (something that is before your script).

The simplest solution is probably to put a `<div id="container"></div>` in the body before your script and append to that instead of the body or put your code in a function and have the body onload event call your function.

See [this article](https://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/tag/documentbodyappendchild/) for description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Internet Options - Security Tab - Internet - click on the "Custom" button then scroll down to the Miscellaneous section."Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints" Find "Active Scripting" then check enable.

Comment: What does this have to do with anything in the question?  Are you implying that scripting isn't enabled in IE8?  An explanation for why this is even relevant to the question would be appropriate.

Comment: you said  it is working perfectly on FireFox and Google Chorome.so, it could be proplem with IE8.It might be the script is not enabled.If it's you have to enable it to work

Answer (score 0):

I noticed than element.style.display doesn't always work with IE8.

Here is a method to improve compatibility :

```
                if (element.style.setAttribute)
                element.style.setAttribute("display", value); 
            else
                element.style.display = value;
```

Best regards,